# ConEmu feature "Flash inactive tab" feature? (a la Console)

Tags: console-application, conemu

Is there a setting on ConEmu similar to the "Flash inactive tabs" setting in the Console app?

When I run three scripts in three different tabs in ConEmu I would like either of the two tabs that are currently not 'in front' (inactive) to blink/flash/highlight/alert me somehow when something new has printed within them.

Console calls this 'Flash inactive tabs' in their similar app.  I'd like to move to ConEmu because it seems to be more powerful/feature packed generally, though as far as I can tell via experimentation and research it lacks this feature which is important to me.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your use-case? Can't imagine... If script is doing smth in the console - in prints continuously. Permanent flashing?

Comment: Thx for looking at my question.  My use case: I am running several instances (one in each Console tab) of a python script (passing it slightly diff arguments in each instance).  The python script reads from a file which is continuously written to.  As the python script parses that file, and finds results/matches based on my arguments, it will print them out.  So figure I have 3 of these running, and every 4 or 5 minutes another 'match' is found in one of the instances, and if that match/print has occured in an inactive tab, it flashes the tab so that I know to click and see what has happened.

Comment: Current ConEmu versions are using WinApi tab control. Flashing is impossible ATM.

Comment: Interesting. Before I used ConEmu I used Console2. I had this feature turned on and soon got very, very tired of it.